# Until when does a BroadcastReceiver receive intents?

Tags: android

I am a bit confused about this part of documentations:

```
A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call to onReceive(Context, Intent).
Once your code returns from this function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer active.
```

What does "no longer active" mean? It means our receiver won't receive any events with the specified type? Or it means the receiver is destroyed and a new one is created when the event occurs?
Is this any difference about this, between registering receiver in manifest file and in code dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"Is this any difference about this, between registering receiver in manifest file and in code dynamically?"`

Yes, there is a difference. Receivers registered in the manifest file will receive all intent-filters it matches, anytime the OS sends them out. This differs from registering a broadcast receiver in code by the broadcast receiver in code will only listen to broadcast intents while you have set it to listen. The reason you would use this method sometimes, as opposed to just registering it in the manifest, is if you wanted to implement ordered broadcast. For example, (you can build your application in such a way that) a broadcast receiver in an activity would have higher priority than the manifest, that way, if you receive an intent that your application handles, you can present a message in the activity because you know that the user much currently be in your app. If the broadcast receiver is not listening in the activity, then you assume the user is not currently using your app so then you may just want to send a notification. I should mention that ordered broadcast have the ability to abort the propagation of a broadcast intent to the next receiver, which is what you would do if you caught the intent in your activity class ,therefore, the manifest file will only get the intent if the receiver in the activity class did not catch it.

The words "no longer active" mean that the broadcast receiver will just stop doing any work for that particular broadcast. It will still listen to any succeeding broadcast intents just fine.

Comment: So when we register the receiver in manifest "EVERY" time the event occurs the receiver will be called not only one time. And when we register it in the code, while that class is running (an activity for example) then "Every" time the event occurs again we have onReceive() called (maybe for many times). So this is a misunderstanding if we think the receiver is launched only once or we will be notified about the event only once.
Please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Your correct. I should mention that ordered broadcast have the ability to abort the propagation of a broadcast intent to the next receiver, which is what you would do if you caught the intent in your activity class. I will update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks. But by saying ' ordered broadcast have the ability to abort the propagation of a broadcast intent to the next receiver' you mean abort it to other intents of the same program not the whole system and apps. right?

Comment: No, it stops it completely. You would only do this for custom broadcast intents, that way only your app will be listening for them. For example, you could possibly have a background service running that     will send broadcast intents with a custom string that only your application would listen to. You would also do this sometimes for system wide events but I am not that familiar with how your app obtains permission for that. Here is a great blog post that will hopefully answer explain a little better. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/01/processing-ordered-broadcasts.html

Answer (score 0):

It means that upon returning from onReceive() the system will consider its process to be empty and **aggressively kill** it so that resources are available for other more important processes.

You will often use a Service in conjunction with a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to keep the containing process active for the entire time of your operation.

Comment: But my main question was something else. Will the receiver continue receiving or not? I mean what if the event occurs another time? Is the onReceive() function called or not?

Comment: Nope. The BroadcastReceiver is as good as dead once the call returns and wont get called. Whatever is running within the onReceive() will be treated as foreground process and will continue running until the return.

Comment: I made a program to test this just now and I feel you're wrong. I defined a button to send a custom broadcast message and whenever I click on it the receiver is called and writes a message

Comment: @user2808671 Sorry misunderstood. It will get triggered for the next event..Also, it's your responsibility to handle the life-cycle correctly.

Comment: Yeah I meant for the next events. And I see this is the same for both receivers defined in manifest file and in code. But of course those defined in code will die after, that section of code (for example an activity which registered a receiver) terminates. After that wont be triggered for next events.